# MySQL - Group orders count by clients numbers

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

I want to group order's count to show how many clients have that number of orders.

I have come up with:

```
select count(*) as quantidade_pedidos, clientes.id
from pedidos
inner join clientes
on pedidos.cliente_id = clientes.id
where pedidos.aprovado = 1
group by quantidade_pedidos
```

but I just can't group by 'quantidade_pedidos' anyway.

Is there any way to group by a temporary column? Another way of doing this? show how many clients (number) have that number of orders placed?

Example
8 orders placed -> 3 clients have 8 orders placed
etc

Comment: It's too obscure to understand this, could you please post some sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query is wrong.  You need to group by `clientes.id`:

```
select count(*) as quantidade_pedidos, c.id
from pedidos p inner join
     clientes c
     on p.cliente_id = c.id
where p.aprovado = 1
group by c.id;
```

In an aggregation query, the *unaggregated* columns go in the `group by`, not the aggregated ones.

Also note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

As for the question in the first line, use a subquery:

```
select quantidade_pedidos, count(*)
from (select count(*) as quantidade_pedidos, c.id
      from pedidos p inner join
           clientes c
           on p.cliente_id = c.id
      where p.aprovado = 1
      group by c.id
     ) x
group by quantidade_pedidos;
```

But given that the query in the question doesn't work, I'm not sure this is what you really want to do.

Comment: If I'm reading it right I think the question is asking how to aggregate the results of this query

Comment: Just wrap it again in another derived table and proceed with it, @lc.

Comment: @ic. . . . Possibly.  But the query in the question is so wrong, that I am guessing that fixing it is the top priority.

Comment: There is just one more little thing: Clients that bought 2 should be also listed in 1 group, clients that bought 3 should also appear in 2 and 1 group and so on...

Comment: @HenriqueM. . . . You should ask that as another question.